Plotly Charts are empty in windows built with electron-builder
I'm trying to build an electron-app with javascript in a linux vm for windows.
The application is working by building it in a docker container with wine.
The problem is, my plotly charts are empty. I just see the empty coordinate system.
When I run or build the app on linux, everything works fine.
Do I need to specify something I'm forgetting?
I'm building everything with the command npm electron-builder --config electron-builder-dev.yml --win --x64 inside the docker container.
My electron-builder-dev.yml config looks like this:
productName: 'My App'
directories:
output: out

buildDependenciesFromSource: true

win:
   target:
      - nsis

nsis:
   artifactName: '${name}-${version}.${ext}'

Everything is working fine in the app. Just the plotly charts are empty.
I would love if someone could help me. Thanks.
